# View and Geolocation fields

Tags: geolocation, drupal-8

There is something wrong with my views and the way it's communicating with geolocation field. Firstly the map is not opening zoomed out so you can see all locations within the view which means I have to zoom out to see all the map markers.

Secondly, whenever the markers are hovered or clicked they don't show any relevant field data or links to the nodes of which the markers are related. I've tried every configuration that I can think of in views Format, Fields and Filter criteria and nothing seems to work.

My entity structure consists of Venues and Events. The Venue has the geolocation field which is entity referenced in the Event with inline_entity_form (complex). The view I'm working from is an Events view with a relationship to Venues. I've also tried putting a geolocation field directly in the Event entity and I still have the same problem.

Does anybody have a solution to these issues?

[screenshot of current map view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WucOP.png)

Comment: without any code provided, this question is too broad to address and cannot be reproduced... please read the help content regarding [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question, and also what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) regarding [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

add attachment for your map and also separate page for the list of your fields.Also in the filter criteria exposed the boundary of you geolocation field.Enable ajax,it works for me.